# SFML, GCC, and undefined symbol for sf::String

Tags: macos, gcc, g++, homebrew, sfml

I have `gcc` 8.1.0 installed through homebrew on macOS 10.13.4. I installed `sfml` 2.4.2_1 through homebrew as well. When I compile this file:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode().getDesktopMode(), "My Window");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            window.clear();
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with `g++-8 sfmltest.cpp -o sfmltest -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network`

I get an undefined reference to sf::String:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)", referenced from:
      _main in cciQ649w.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I realize that I shouldn't need all of those libraries. I was including them hoping to get rid of the undefined symbols error. If I compile the same file with the same libraries using `clang++`, everything compiles just fine.

My guess is that homebrew is using `clang` to compile and install `sfml` and that the produced abi is incompatible with `gcc`. Can anyone confirm this? Is this something that I can fix? It's no problem to use `clang++` for me. I would prefer to use `g++` just because I want to.

Comment: I'm gonna guess it has something to do with different standard libraries. I'm guessing the SFML libraries were compiled with libc++, so the `sf::String::String` constructor is expecting a libc++ `std::locale`, but when you're compiling with `g++-8` it's passing `libstdc++`'s `std::locale`.

Comment: This may also be because of GCC's interpretation of link libraries. Off-hand I would expect undefined symbols based on your command line alone, because object files and libraries have to be listed _before_ any object files they depend on. Try `g++-8 sfmltest.cpp -o sfmltest -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`. Audio and network should not be needed here.

Comment: @ravnsgaard, that was not it. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: OK. Then I think Cornstalks is probably right that you have a mixup of standard libraries somehow.